# Extract flight arrival data from web

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to scrape arrival data from [Flight Radar 24](https://www.flightradar24.com)

My script takes extremely long time to scrape the data. Is there any way I can speed up the scraping process?

Here's my script:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import requests

def getArrivals():
    urls = {
    'Alor Island Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ard/arrivals',
    'Ambon Pattimura Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/amq/arrivals',
    'Atambua Haliwen Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/abu/arrivals',
    'Babo Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bxb/arrivals',
    'Bajawa Turelelo Soa Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bjw/arrivals',
    'Balikpapan Sepinggan Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bpn/arrivals',
    'Banda Aceh International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/btj/arrivals',
    'Bandar Lampung Radin Inten II Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/tkg/arrivals',
    'Bandung Husein Sastranegara International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bdo/arrivals',
    'Banjarmasin Syamsudin Noor Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bdj/arrivals',
    'Batam Hang Nadim Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bth/arrivals',
    'Batu Licin Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/btw/arrivals',
    'Bau-Bau Betoambari Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/buw/arrivals',
    'Bengkulu Fatmawati Soekarno Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bks/arrivals',
    'Biak Frans Kaisiepo Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bik/arrivals',
    'Bima Sultan Muhammad Salahudin Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bmu/arrivals',
    'Blimbingsari Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bwx/arrivals',
    'Buol Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/uol/arrivals',
    'Dekai Nop Goliat Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/dex/arrivals',
    'Denpasar Ngurah Rai International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/dps/arrivals',
    'Dumai Pinang Kampai Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/dum/arrivals',
    'Ende H. Hasan Aroeboesman Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ene/arrivals',
    'Fakfak Torea Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/fkq/arrivals',
    'Gorontalo Jalaluddin Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/gto/arrivals',
    'Gunung Sitoli Binaka Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/gns/arrivals',
    'Jakarta Halim Perdanakusuma Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/hlp/arrivals',
    'Jakarta Soekarno Hatta International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/cgk/arrivals',
    'Jambi Sultan Thaha Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/djb/arrivals',
    'Jayapura Sentani Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/djj/arrivals',
    'Jember Notohadinegoro Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/jbb/arrivals',
    'Kaimana Utarom Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/kng/arrivals',
    'Kalimarau Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bej/arrivals',
    'Kebar Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/keq/arrivals',
    'Kendari Haluoleo Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/kdi/arrivals',
    'Ketapang Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ktg/arrivals',
    'Kotabaru Gusti Syamsir Alam Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/kbu/arrivals',
    'Kupang El Tari Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/koe/arrivals',
    'Labuan Bajo Komodo Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/lbj/arrivals',
    'Labuha Oesman Sadik Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/lah/arrivals',
    'Langgur Karel Sadsuitubun Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/luv/arrivals',
    'Larantuka Gewayantana Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/lka/arrivals',
    'Lewoleba Wunopito Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/lwe/arrivals',
    'Lhokseumawe Malikus Saleh Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/lsw/arrivals',
    'Lombok International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/lop/arrivals',
    'Lubuklinggau Silampari Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/llj/arrivals',
    'Luwuk Bubung Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/luw/arrivals',
    'Majalengka Kertajati International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/kjt/arrivals',
    'Makassar Sultan Hasanuddin International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/upg/arrivals',
    'Malang Abdul Rachman Saleh Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/mlg/arrivals',
    'Malinau Kolonel RA Bessing Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/lnu/arrivals',
    'Mamuju Tampa Padang Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/mju/arrivals',
    'Manado Sam Ratulangi International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/mdc/arrivals',
    'Manokwari Rendani Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/mkw/arrivals',
    'Matak Tarempa Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/mwk/arrivals',
    'Maumere Frans Seda Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/mof/arrivals',
    'Medan Kuala Namu International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/kno/arrivals',
    'Melangguane Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/mna/arrivals',
    'Merauke Mopah International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/mkq/arrivals',
    'Muara Bungo Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/buu/arrivals',
    'Nabire Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/nbx/arrivals',
    'Nanga Pinoh Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/npo/arrivals',
    'Nunukan Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/nnx/arrivals',
    'Oksibil Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/okl/arrivals',
    'Padang Minangkabau International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/pdg/arrivals',
    'Palangkaraya Tjilik Riwut Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/pky/arrivals',
    'Palembang International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/plm/arrivals',
    'Palopo Lagaligo Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/llo/arrivals',
    'Palu Mutiara Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/plw/arrivals',
    'Pangkal Pinang Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/pgk/arrivals',
    'Pangkalan Bun Iskandar Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/pkn/arrivals',
    'Pekanbaru Sultan Syarif Kasim II Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/pku/arrivals',
    'Pomala Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/pum/arrivals',
    'Pontianak Supadio Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/pnk/arrivals',
    'Putussibau Pangsuma Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/psu/arrivals',
    'Raha Sugimanuru Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/raq/arrivals',
    'Ranai Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ntx/arrivals',
    'Rengat Japura Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/rgt/arrivals',
    'Roti David C. Saudale Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/rti/arrivals',
    'Ruteng Frans Sales Lega Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/rtg/arrivals',
    'Sabang Maimun Saleh Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/sbg/arrivals',
    'Samarinda AP Tumenggung Pranoto Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/aap/arrivals',
    'Sampit Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/smq/arrivals',
    'Saumlaki Mathilda Batlayeri Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/sxk/arrivals',
    'Selayar Islands H. Aroeppala Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ksr/arrivals',
    'Semarang Achmad Yani International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/srg/arrivals',
    'Sibolga Ferdinand Lumban Tobing Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/flz/arrivals',
    'Siborong-Borong Silangit Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/dtb/arrivals',
    'Sintang Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/sqg/arrivals',
    'Sorong Dominique Edward Osok Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/soq/arrivals',
    'Sumbawa Besar Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/swq/arrivals',
    'Sumenep Trunojoyo Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/sup/arrivals',
    'Surabaya Juanda International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/sub/arrivals',
    'Surakarta Adisumarmo International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/soc/arrivals',
    'Tahuna Naha Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/nah/arrivals',
    'Tambolaka Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/tmc/arrivals',
    'Tana Toraja Pongtiku Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ttr/arrivals',
    'Tanahmerah Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/tmh/arrivals',
    'Tanjung Pandan Buluh Tumbang Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/tjq/arrivals',
    'Tanjung Pinang Raja Haji Fisabilillah Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/tnj/arrivals',
    'Tanjung Selor Tanjung Harapan Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/tjs/arrivals',
    'Tarakan Juwata International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/trk/arrivals',
    'Tasikmalaya Cibeureum Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/tsy/arrivals',
    'Ternate Babullah Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/tte/arrivals',
    'Timika Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/tim/arrivals',
    'Waingapu Mau Hau Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/wgp/arrivals',
    'Wamena Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/wmx/arrivals',
    'Yogyakarta Adisucipto International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/jog/arrivals',
    'Yogyakarta International Airport': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/yia/arrivals'
    }
    
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    
    airport_name = []
    times = []
    dates = []
    flight=[]
    flightfrom = []
    airlines = []
    aircrafts = []
    flight_status = []
    abbrs = []
    for key, value in urls.items():
        driver.get(value)
        time.sleep(4)
        scroll_pause_time = 1 # You can set your own pause time. My laptop is a bit slow so I use 1 sec
        screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   # get the screen height of the web
        i = 1
    
        while True:
            # scroll one screen height each time
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))  
            i += 1
            time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
            # update scroll height each time after scrolled, as the scroll height can change after we scrolled the page
            scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  
            # Break the loop when the height we need to scroll to is larger than the total scroll height
            if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
                break
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    
        #Time
        time_div=soup.find_all('div',{'class':'col-xs-3 col-sm-3 p-xxs'})
        for a in time_div:
            time_span = a.find_all('span',{'class':'ng-binding'})
            for b in time_span:
                time_text = b.text.strip()
                times.append(time_text)
    
        #Date
        date_tr=soup.find_all('tr',{'class':'hidden-xs hidden-sm ng-scope'})
        for d in date_tr:
            date = d.get('data-date')
            dates.append(date)
    
        #flight
        flight_td=soup.find_all('td',{'class':'p-l-s cell-flight-number'})
        for a in flight_td:
            aflight = a.find_all('a',{'class':'notranslate ng-binding'})
            for b in aflight:
                flight_text = b.get('title')
                flight.append(flight_text)
    
        #from
        asal = [link.get_text().strip() for link in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "hide-mobile-only ng-binding"})]
        flightfrom.extend(asal)
    
        abbreviation=soup.find_all('div',{'ng-show':'(objFlight.flight.airport.origin)'})
        for a in abbreviation:
            abbr_a = a.find_all('a',{'class':'fs-10 fbold notranslate ng-binding'})
            for b in abbr_a:
                abbr_text = b.text.strip()
                abbrs.append(abbr_text)
    
        #airline
        airline_td=soup.find_all('td',{'class':'cell-airline'})
        for a in airline_td:
            airline_a = a.find_all('a',{'class':'notranslate ng-binding'})
            for b in airline_a:
                airline = b.get('title')
                airlines.append(airline)
    
        #aircraft
        aircraft_td = soup.find_all('td')
        for a in aircraft_td:
            aircraft_span = a.find_all('span',{'class':'notranslate ng-binding'})
            for b in aircraft_span:
                aircraft = b.text.strip()
                aircrafts.append(aircraft)
    
        #flight_status
        status_td = soup.find_all('td',{'class':'ng-binding'})
        for a in status_td:
            status_span = a.find_all('span',{'class':'ng-binding'})
            for b in status_span:
                status = b.text.strip()
                flight_status.append(status)
            
        airport_tmp = [key] * len(asal)
        airport_name.extend(airport_tmp)

        df = pd.DataFrame()
        df["Dates"] = dates
        df["Time"] = times
        df["Flight"] = flight
        df["From"] = list(map(' '.join, zip(flightfrom, abbrs)))
        df["Airlines"] = airlines
        df["Aircrafts"] = aircrafts
        df["Status"] = flight_status
        df["Airport"] = airport_name
    return(df)
```

Comment: @PavloSlavynskyy Whether it is or not, is not our concern. If Flight Radar has a problem with this question, they can sent an e-mail to legal@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @lockey If your motivation to delete your code was that you're concerned about legal liability, one option is to request that this question be dissociated from your account. The code will remain up but will be tied to a new, anonymous account instead of yours. However, deleting the question or the code in it is against policy and considered vandalism.

Answer (score 4):

First: As @PavloSlavynskyy warns, FlightRadar24 has attempted to make it very clear that they do **not** want you to scrape their site or use their API. Among other verbiage, they say:

> Copyright (c) 2014-2021 Flightradar24 AB. All rights reserved.
>
> The contents of this file and all derived data are the property of Flightradar24 AB for use exclusively by its products and applications. Using, modifying or redistributing the data without the prior written permission of Flightradar24 AB is not allowed and may result in prosecutions.
>
> [...]
>
> Please note that scraping or any other form of automatic data download is in violation of our Terms of Service (https://www.flightradar24.com/terms-and-conditions) and may result in lost access to Flightradar24. Please contact business@fr24.com should you wish to have access to our data services.

Also note that if you attempt to hit their API directly without configuring it correctly, you get an  [HTTP 451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_451), in case you hadn't gotten the point.

I am not a legal expert. You have been warned.

As for an actual review:

- Consider moving your URL list to a separate JSON file
- Your dictionary of URLs should remove the  `Airport` suffix seen on every title, and don't store the URL - only store what changes, which is the airport code
- You've decided to take the worst of all worlds - you have the slowness and inefficiency of Selenium, but you've thrown away the result of its DOM and are parsing its source into BeautifulSoup for some reason. You don't need to do either of these.
- If you do some trivial network analysis of their website and hit the REST API the same way that your browser does, Requests on its own - with no HTML parsing needed, only JSON - works fine. I am not going to spell out how this is done.

Comment: Thank you for the warning, I didn't use this code for business affairs, just for learning about dynamic web. Can I ask about the point two? Why should I remove the ```Airport``` suffix to be ```'Alor Island': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ard/arrivals'```? what is the effect? pls explain thankyou

Comment: From the point three, did you not recommend Selenium to scrape dynamic website? Do you have any recommendation for that in order to scrape fastly and efficient?

Comment: _Why should I remove the Airport suffix to be 'Alor Island': 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ard/arrivals'_ - you shouldn't; it should be `'Alor Island': 'ard'`. This is to remove redundancy from your stored data.

Comment: Correct; Selenium should not be used to scrape here. In general it should be avoided unless strictly necessary, and in the past few years I've only encountered one case of many that needed it.

Comment: It actually didn't answered the second point, I used selenium because the code contains javascript